# Why do I receive a ClassCastException when modelling a One-to-Many relation with a composite key?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I'm trying to model a One-to-Many relation in which the foreign key is part of a composite key. Unfortunately, I run into the following error message:

`class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne`

My entities are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "point_in_time")
class PointInTime(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val note: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "symptom")
    val symptoms: Set<Symptom>
) {
    @field:Column(updatable = false)
    val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now()
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "symptom")
@IdClass(SymptomId::class)
class Symptom(
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "point_in_time_id", nullable = false)
    val pointInTime: PointInTime,
    @Id
    val category: String,
    @Id
    val symptom: String,
    val strength: Strength
)
```

```
class SymptomId (
    val pointInTime: Long,
    val category: String,
    val symptom: String
): Serializable
```

What is the cause of this exception and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a simple bug in one of the dependencies. I fixed the problem by going from spring boot version 3.1.4 to 3.2.1.